# C# Dynamic Table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, dynamic

I want to create a table dynamically. I have limited space for where this table will fit, so I would want to set the max rows to 10.

The first two columns would get populated, when it hits 10 then create another two columns fill it with another 10 rows and then create another two columns and so on.

How could I go about doing this or what would be the best way to do the loops etc?

Comment: What are you talking about? A database table? An html table? Or maybe winforms, silverlight, wpf... your question isn't clear at all. Please elaborate and explain accurately, otherwise noone can help you.

Comment: Is this in WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net HTML? XNA? wxWidgets? ... This very much affects the answer you need.

Comment: In the future try to post an example of the translation you want to do so it's easier for readers to visualize what you are looking for. I posted below what I assumed your translation was.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to translate data from his form:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
E 5
F 6
G 7
```

into

```
A 1 D 4 G 7
B 2 E 5
C 3 F 6
```

If so, here's how you could accomplish that:

First I used a class to contain each pair of data items (like A,1) like so:

```
    class DataElement
    {
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
    }
```

then I built a helper function that accepts List and converts it to a table in your format:

```
    private const int MaxRows = 3; //Configure how many Rows in the table
    private const int NumColsPerElement = 2; //Configure how many columns per element

    static System.Data.DataTable BuildTabularTableElements(List<DataElement> elements)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

        int columnCount = (((elements.Count + MaxRows - 1) / MaxRows)) * NumColsPerElement;          

        for (int x = 0; x < columnCount; x++) //Add enough columns
            dt.Columns.Add();

        for (int x = 0; x < Math.Min(MaxRows, elements.Count); x++) //Add enough rows
            dt.Rows.Add();
        for (int x = 0; x < elements.Count; x++)
        {
            int curCol = (x / MaxRows) * NumColsPerElement; //Determine the current col/row
            int curRow = x % MaxRows;

            dt.Rows[curRow][curCol] = elements[x]First you need a.Value1; //Place the data in the correct row/column
            dt.Rows[curRow][curCol+1] = elements[x].Value2;
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Finally to test, use this:

```
       List<DataElement> e = new List<DataElement>();
       e.Add(new DataElement() { Value1 = "1", Value2 = "2" });
       e.Add(new DataElement() { Value1 = "3", Value2 = "4" });
       e.Add(new DataElement() { Value1 = "5", Value2 = "6" });
       e.Add(new DataElement() { Value1 = "7", Value2 = "8" });

       System.Data.DataTable dt = BuildTabularTableElements(e);
```

Notice I used constants to control how many rows and columns to use. In my example I used a 3 Row max and 2 column per data element. This surely could be cleaned up a bit but it does what I assume you wanted. You could pull in the constants to be method parameters and change over List to use a standard array in order to provide high flexibility so you could use arbitrary sized tables and column counts, but I'll leave that up to you if you need it.